# Angular Material Dialog: dialogRef.afterClosed() subscription not triggered

Tags: angular, angular-material, subscription, mat-dialog

i am using material ui to open a component inside of a Mat-Dialog. When I close the dialog, my subscription to the dialogRef wont trigger.

The parentComponent calls the editCatering() to open the dialog.

parentComponent:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export class BewirtungListTableComponent ...{
   
    constructor(..., public dialog: MatDialog,...) {}
    

editCatering(data){
        this.requestSub = this.guestService.getGuestsByCateringId(bewirtung.id).subscribe((guest: Guest[]) => {
            let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BewirtungEditComponent, {
                data: {data, guest},
                disableClose: true,
                autoFocus: false 
            });

            dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
                console.log("dialog closed")
                console.log(result)
            })
    };
```

Then the dialogComponent closes on the onSubmit() call;

```
...
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
...

export class BewirtungEditComponent ...
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,..., public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BewirtungEditComponent>){}

onSubmit() {
...
            this.updateSub = this.bewirtungService.updateCatering(cateringCreate).subscribe(
                (b: Bewirtung) => {
                    ...
                    this.dialogRef.close(b)
                },
                () => this.notificationService.error('Die Bewirtung konnte nicht geändert werden.')
            );
        }
        else {...}
    }
```

I checked the dialogRef in the states of the parentComponent and the dialogComponent: They have the same ID and after closing the dialogRef`s state changes to 2.

Any idea why the dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe() doesnt do anything?

**UPDATE**

I also tested to move the afterClosed().subscription to the dialogComponent:

```
onSubmit() {
            ...
            this.updateSub = this.bewirtungService.updateCatering(cateringCreate).subscribe(
                (b: Bewirtung) => {
                    ...
                    this.dialogRef.close(b);
                    console.log(this.dialogRef)
                    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(()=>console.log("after closed editComponent"))
                },
                () => this.notificationService.error('Die Bewirtung konnte nicht geändert werden.')
            );
        }
```

But even there i dont get anything.

Comment: are you sure `this.dialogRef.close(b)` is executed ? Is there any error in the console ? Sometimes the code crashed while closing the modal...

Comment: yes. the dialog closes properly and there are no console errors.

Comment: to make sure i removed the form from the dialog and also all other functionality. still the same:the dialog closes, but the afterClosed() wont trigger.

Comment: Your code looks fine, no obvious reason for it not to work. Can you reproduce it in a plunker/fiddle/anything ? Otherwise, sometimes all you have to do is stop the server, and rerun ng serve...

Comment: I also did that.. still doesnt work.

I also tried to use the closeAll() on the dialog itself and subscribed to the dialog.afterAllClosed.. Same thing. it doesnt trigger.

i did a simple rebuild in a stackblitz and there it worked.

Comment: Have you tried adding a second parameter (the error callback) to the subscribe of `afterClosed()` ?

Comment: Quote: "are you sure this.dialogRef.close(b) is executed ? Is there any error in the console ? Sometimes the code crashed while closing the modal... – Random 16 hours ago"

After checking again, I found the problem. onDestroy() I unsubscibe() from my subs and there was one subscription causing an error. I dont know why the console didnt show the error msg, but this was the reason it didnt work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: same problem here, nothing makes any sense...